# SDL Is LInked with another version

Tags: python, pygame

I Made A Game In Pycharm And When I finished it it was working fine until last week when i run The game it tells me RuntimeError: SDL compiled with version 2.0.22, linked to 2.24.0
so what is SDL and how do i solve it and why it happens and here is the code Thank You For Reviewing My Code

```
 import pygame
 pygame.init()


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1340, 840
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT = 20, 100
BALL_RADIUS = 7

SCORE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)
WINNING_SCORE = 10


  class Paddle:
    COLOR = WHITE
    VEL = 6

     def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
      self.x = self.original_x = x
      self.y = self.original_y = y
      self.width = width
      self.height = height

    def draw(self, win):
     pygame.draw.rect(
        win, self.COLOR, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

   def move(self, up=True):
    if up:
        self.y -= self.VEL
    else:
        self.y += self.VEL

   def reset(self):
     self.x = self.original_x
     self.y = self.original_y


class Ball:
MAX_VEL = 7
COLOR = WHITE

def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
    self.x = self.original_x = x
    self.y = self.original_y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.x_vel = self.MAX_VEL
    self.y_vel = 0

def draw(self, win):
    pygame.draw.circle(win, self.COLOR, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

def move(self):
    self.x += self.x_vel
    self.y += self.y_vel

def reset(self):
    self.x = self.original_x
    self.y = self.original_y
    self.y_vel = 0
    self.x_vel *= -1


def draw(win, paddles, ball, left_score, right_score):
 win.fill(BLACK)

 left_score_text = SCORE_FONT.render(f"{left_score}", 1, WHITE)
 right_score_text = SCORE_FONT.render(f"{right_score}", 1, WHITE)
 win.blit(left_score_text, (WIDTH//4 - left_score_text.get_width()//2, 20))
 win.blit(right_score_text, (WIDTH * (3/4) -
                            right_score_text.get_width()//2, 20))

for paddle in paddles:
    paddle.draw(win)

for i in range(10, HEIGHT, HEIGHT//20):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        continue
    pygame.draw.rect(win, WHITE, (WIDTH//2 - 5, i, 10, HEIGHT//20))

    ball.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_collision(ball, left_paddle, right_paddle):
 if ball.y + ball.radius >= HEIGHT:
    ball.y_vel *= -1
 elif ball.y - ball.radius <= 0:
    ball.y_vel *= -1

 if ball.x_vel < 0:
    if ball.y >= left_paddle.y and ball.y <= left_paddle.y + left_paddle.height:
        if ball.x - ball.radius <= left_paddle.x + left_paddle.width:
            ball.x_vel *= -1

            middle_y = left_paddle.y + left_paddle.height / 2
            difference_in_y = middle_y - ball.y
            reduction_factor = (left_paddle.height / 2) / ball.MAX_VEL
            y_vel = difference_in_y / reduction_factor
            ball.y_vel = -1 * y_vel

else:
    if ball.y >= right_paddle.y and ball.y <= right_paddle.y + right_paddle.height:
        if ball.x + ball.radius >= right_paddle.x:
            ball.x_vel *= -1

            middle_y = right_paddle.y + right_paddle.height / 2
            difference_in_y = middle_y - ball.y
            reduction_factor = (right_paddle.height / 2) / ball.MAX_VEL
            y_vel = difference_in_y / reduction_factor
            ball.y_vel = -1 * y_vel


def handle_paddle_movement(keys, left_paddle, right_paddle):
 if keys[pygame.K_w] and left_paddle.y - left_paddle.VEL >= 0:
    left_paddle.move(up=True)
if keys[pygame.K_s] and left_paddle.y + left_paddle.VEL + left_paddle.height <= 
HEIGHT:
    left_paddle.move(up=False)

if keys[pygame.K_UP] and right_paddle.y - right_paddle.VEL >= 0:
    right_paddle.move(up=True)
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and right_paddle.y + right_paddle.VEL + right_paddle.height <= 
HEIGHT:
    right_paddle.move(up=False)


def main():
 run = True
 clock = pygame.time.Clock()

left_paddle = Paddle(10, HEIGHT//2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT //
                     2, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT)
right_paddle = Paddle(WIDTH - 10 - PADDLE_WIDTH, HEIGHT //
                      2 - PADDLE_HEIGHT//2, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT)
ball = Ball(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2, BALL_RADIUS)

left_score = 0
right_score = 0

while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    draw(WIN, [left_paddle, right_paddle], ball, left_score, right_score)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    handle_paddle_movement(keys, left_paddle, right_paddle)

    ball.move()
    handle_collision(ball, left_paddle, right_paddle)

    if ball.x < 0:
        right_score += 1
        ball.reset()
    elif ball.x > WIDTH:
        left_score += 1
        ball.reset()

    won = False
    if left_score >= WINNING_SCORE:
        won = True
        win_text = "Left Player Won!"
    elif right_score >= WINNING_SCORE:
        won = True
        win_text = "Right Player Won!"

    if won:
        text = SCORE_FONT.render(win_text, 1, WHITE)
        WIN.blit(text, (WIDTH//2 - text.get_width() //
                        2, HEIGHT//2 - text.get_height()//2))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(5000)
        ball.reset()
        left_paddle.reset()
        right_paddle.reset()
        left_score = 0
        right_score = 0

   pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `pygame` is wrapper on C/C++ library [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/). Maybe system updated `SDL` but `pygame` still need older version.

Comment: What OS? Add installed packages with names similar to SDL/sdl/pygame to the question. Your problem (as furas also mentioned) is there is a difference in versions. You are using one version to compile the python program and a different version installed default.

Comment: @AmmarUchia you still having this issue?